# Memory usage by Java processes

Tags: java, memory-usage

I notices that applications use almost all memory on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

Can you look into my `htop` screen and let me know whether this situation is normal?

[image: Ubuntu server memory usage]

There are many processes for two java application, for both of them all related threads use 3.7% and 4.8% of memory. Is it for each thread or only for root process 3.7%?

How can I see in percentage which process use this percentage of memory and how many? I have 60 processes with 3.7% so it is much more than 100%

Answer (score 1):

All threads in a Java process share almost all memory.  Each thread will have a local stack which is usually less than a megabyte.  As you see all the relate threads show the same memory utilization.  The 60 related processes showing 3.7% memory utilization might be using 3.8% of available memory.